# Converting Assembly x64 code to C

Tags: disassembly, assembly, decompilation, x86-64

I have the following code:

```
0000000000400526 <main>:
  400526:   55                      push   rbp
  400527:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  40052a:   48 83 ec 20             sub    rsp,0x20
  40052e:   89 7d ec                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],edi
  400531:   48 89 75 e0             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rsi
  400535:   c7 45 f4 4d 3c 2b 1a    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x1a2b3c4d
  40053c:   48 8d 45 f4             lea    rax,[rbp-0xc]
  400540:   48 89 45 f8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
  400544:   c7 45 f0 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x0
  40054b:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  40054f:   0f b6 00                movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rax]
  400552:   0f be c0                movsx  eax,al
  400555:   c1 e0 18                shl    eax,0x18
  400558:   89 c2                   mov    edx,eax
  40055a:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  40055e:   48 83 c0 01             add    rax,0x1
  400562:   0f b6 00                movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rax]
  400565:   0f be c0                movsx  eax,al
  400568:   c1 e0 10                shl    eax,0x10
  40056b:   09 c2                   or     edx,eax
  40056d:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  400571:   48 83 c0 02             add    rax,0x2
  400575:   0f b6 00                movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rax]
  400578:   0f be c0                movsx  eax,al
  40057b:   c1 e0 08                shl    eax,0x8
  40057e:   09 c2                   or     edx,eax
  400580:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  400584:   48 83 c0 03             add    rax,0x3
  400588:   0f b6 00                movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rax]
  40058b:   0f be c0                movsx  eax,al
  40058e:   09 d0                   or     eax,edx
  400590:   89 45 f0                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],eax
  400593:   8b 55 f0                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
  400596:   8b 45 f4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc]
  400599:   89 c6                   mov    esi,eax
  40059b:   bf 44 06 40 00          mov    edi,0x400644 ; "a = %#x\nb = %#x\n"
  4005a0:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  4005a5:   e8 56 fe ff ff          call   400400 <printf@plt>
  4005aa:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  4005af:   c9                      leave
  4005b0:   c3                      ret
  4005b1:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
  4005b8:   00 00 00
  4005bb:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
```

This is a segment of x64 assembly code, and I would like to rewrite this code into C. I've been reading Assembly books all day, and I'm still having some difficulty. I just want to understand what this code is doing. From messing around, I think that it performs some operations on an int (that's why I think the DWORD is there) and a long (that's why the QWORD is there). I think that this is true because I recompiled C code with those data structures and those words appeared in the Assembly equivalent, but I could be wrong.

Any help is appreciated in decoding this code.'

---

**For Amigag:** second segment of code

```
0000000000400966 <my_tolower>:
  400966:   55                      push   rbp
  400967:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  40096a:   48 89 7d f8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rdi
  40096e:   eb 2d                   jmp    40099d <my_tolower+0x37>
  400970:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  400974:   0f b6 00                movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rax]
  400977:   3c 40                   cmp    al,0x40
  400979:   7e 1d                   jle    400998 <my_tolower+0x32>
  40097b:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  40097f:   0f b6 00                movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rax]
  400982:   3c 5a                   cmp    al,0x5a
  400984:   7f 12                   jg     400998 <my_tolower+0x32>
  400986:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  40098a:   0f b6 00                movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rax]
  40098d:   83 c0 20                add    eax,0x20
  400990:   89 c2                   mov    edx,eax
  400992:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  400996:   88 10                   mov    BYTE PTR [rax],dl
  400998:   48 83 45 f8 01          add    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x1
  40099d:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  4009a1:   0f b6 00                movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rax]
  4009a4:   84 c0                   test   al,al
  4009a6:   75 c8                   jne    400970 <my_tolower+0xa>
  4009a8:   90                      nop
  4009a9:   5d                      pop    rbp
  4009aa:   c3                      ret    
  4009ab:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the best tool for rewriting assembly to C is IDA Graph View, which is toggled with <kbd>space</kbd>.
It let you see the function as [Basic Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block), connected by control flow instructions. In this specific function, I cannot spot any jumps so you will see one long block.

The first thing you usually see in a function is the function prologue which sets up the stack frame.

```
  400526:   55                      push   rbp
  400527:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  40052a:   48 83 ec 20             sub    rsp,0x20
```

second, as 64 bit calling convention suggests, the first parameters are passed by registers, other are passed on the stack.
The used registers are os-dependent (see table 5 at [Agner Fog calling conventions](http://agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf)).
You an see that the function probably gets 2 parameters (edi for 32 bit variable for `argc` and 64 bit for `argv`)

You can see that a "magic" value (`0x1a2b3c4`) is saved in a local variable and a pointer to it is created. Note that when it's saved, it is stored as [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian), which means the order of bytes is reversed.

```
  400535:   c7 45 f4 4d 3c 2b 1a    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x1a2b3c4d
  40053c:   48 8d 45 f4             lea    rax,[rbp-0xc]
  400540:   48 89 45 f8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
```

And his first byte is read to eax as a signed byte and multiplied by `2^0x18 (=2^24)`.
The fact that it's signed doesn't affect anything in this case, because the sign bit is always off (as `0x1a`, `0x2b`, `0x3c` and `0x4d` are all below 128)

```
  40054f:   0f b6 00                movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rax]
  400552:   0f be c0                movsx  eax,al
  400555:   c1 e0 18                shl    eax,0x18
```

And in a similar way, a value is calculated using next bytes, multiplied by 0x10 (=16), 8 and 1 (implicitly) respectively. results are stored in edi, and `or`ed with the previous value.

We can conclude that our function is something like that:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int calculated_value;  // represents the use of edi to store the result
     int magic_value = 0x1A2B3C4D;  // note that although i am using int, i mean uint32_t, a variable that has 4 bytes - a DWORD.
     char *magic_ptr = (char *) &magic_value;  // the values are read byte-by-byte, or char-by-char
     calculated_value = magic_ptr[0] << 24;
     calculated_value |= magic_ptr[1] << 16;
     calculated_value |= magic_ptr[2] << 8;
     calculated_value |= magic_ptr[3];  // note that at the last or, the result is saved at eax as edi will soon be used to pass the first parameter to printf

     printf("a = %#x\nb = %#x\n", magic_value, calculated_value);
}
```

So, what we can see is that the magic value is read back to a variable, while saving the little-endianness, which means we will get the reversed byte order if the `magic_value`.
Thus, we can expect the output to be:

> a = 0x1a2b3c4d
>   b = 0x4d3c2b1a

---

Also, as a general note, this code have could utilize loops to perform the read.

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int i;
     int calculated_value = 0;  // represents the use of edi to store the result
     int magic_value = 0x1A2B3C4D;  // note that although i am using int, i mean uint32_t, a variable that has 4 bytes - a DWORD.
     char *magic_ptr = (char *) &magic_value;  // the values are read byte-by-byte, or char-by-char
     for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     {
         calculated_value <<= 8;
         calculated_value = magic_ptr[i];
     }
     printf("a = %#x\nb = %#x\n", magic_value, calculated_value);
}
```

---

EDIT: As to your second code.
Here we can see jumps, so I created a graph view of the code. it makes reading it much easier.
A bit of info on the graph: a green line means that the jump happens if a condition is met. A red line means that the jump happens if the condition is false. A blue line means that the jump is unconditional, it will always jump.
Let's go through it and see what happens.

[image: A graph view of the second code]

The first thing we get to see after the function prologue is a single parameter is saved at `rbp-0x8`.
On the block of `0x40099d` we can see that the input is probably `char *ptr`, it dereference the pointer and read it's value.
From the `test al, al` we can assume that the value is a string (and not just binary data, it is *probably* related to user input) and we stop once we have read the null terminator (`\x00` = 0).

The next block we will check is `0x400970`. All it does is checking if the char pointed by `rbp-0x8` is smaller or equal to `0x40` (`0x40` is ascii for '@', `0x41` is 'A'). If it is, it `continue`s (the single-line block at `0x400998`).

So far, our function is something like:

```
void my_tolower(char *str)
{
    while(str[i] != '\x00')
    {
        if(str[i] < 'A')  // as opposed to <= '@'. I can't remember I saw a code ever caring about '@'.
        {
            str += 1;  // skipping the current character
            continue;
        }
        // unknown code for now
    }
}
```

Looking at `0x40097b`, we can see a similar code, but it checks the character is smaller than `0x5A` (=ascii of `Z`). so we can write those conditions in a single if:

```
if(str[i] < 'A' || str[i] > 'Z')
```

Last block (`0x400986`). We now know that str[i] contains an upper-case letter.
The code takes the character and add `0x20` to it. `0x20` is ascii for  (space) and (`a` - `A`). It saves the result back to the string and continues.

```
  400992:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  400996:   88 10                   mov    BYTE PTR [rax],dl
```

Looking at `0x4009a8`, no result is passed to `rax`, that means the function probably doesn't return a value.

So, out functions look something like that:

```
void my_tolower(char *str)
{
    while(str[i] != '\x00')
    {
        if(str[i] < 'A' || str[i] > 'Z')  // as opposed to <= '@'. I can't remember I saw a code ever caring about '@'.
        {
            continue;
        }
        str[i] = str[i] + 'a' - 'A';
        str += 1;
    }
}
```

We could also rewrite the function to show the single block that increments the pointer, which i believe is how the original code looked like. it makes more sense logically that we change the string if a condition was met, not if a condition is not met.

```
void my_tolower(char *str)  // name was taken from 4009a6 and the first line of function
{
    while(str[i] != '\x00')
    {
        if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')  // as opposed to <= '@'. I can't remember I saw a code ever caring about '@'.
        {
            str[i] = str[i] + 'a' - 'A';
        }
        str += 1;  // this is the block at 400998, that always happen
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! There is just one last segment of code that I'm having trouble deciphering. I've accepted your answer, though. I added it to the original post to see if you can help me? I do not have IDA Graph View (though, I saw it as a suggested application earlier) as it is pay-per-download, and I plan on using Assembly again.

Comment: @stackofhay42 i've edited the answer